# Bootstrap and fieldset

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I hate that bootstrap has nullified the fieldset tag and legend.

Q: Is there a way to tell the browser to use the default fieldset & legend rendering without downloading a local copy of bootstrap and removing those lines from bootstrap.css? I want to leave bootstrap.css alone so that I can use a cdn.

I'm thinking of something like the !important flag.

Comment: Can you put together a quick jsfiddle to showcase the problems you are having?  Code please.

Comment: [Example](http://www.phillipsenn.com/Matrix/Bootstrap/Fieldset.cfm)

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69PHc/)